# Execute a timeline of actions

Tags: android

i have a bunch of actions that need to be executed in an android app after an exact waiting period.

action 1: start after 1000ms
action 2: start after 2000ms
action 3: start after 3000ms

i developed 2 different approaches to achieve this. one with a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and one with a loop. the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor results in an OutOfMemoryException if there are too many actions to execute and feels also not so precise. the version with the loop works actually quite well and feels precise, but uses of course an awful lot of CPU power.

does anyone have experience with a similar task and could give me a hint what the best method is?

oh, this will of course run in an AsyncTask.

thx
simon

```
int[] times = new int[]{ 1000, 2000, 3000 };

// 1. use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(times.length);
for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
    ex.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("timer");
        }
    }, times[i], TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

// 2. use loop
int i = 0;
int max = times.length;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(i < max){
    int t = times[i];
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    if(diff >= t){
        System.out.println("loop");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option 1 is significantly better than your option two because you aren't needlessly churning as much CPU time as you can get to run it.

Comment: yeah sure, but in the real app i do that with about 600 actions (600 Runnable objects) which crashes the app with an OutOfMemoryException. also the timing seems not be a bit off.

Comment: If you don't have memory to schedule your workload, your workload might be a bit much for your system! However the second approach could work better with a simple addition: at the end of the loop, call Thread.sleep() for the time remaining until the next time you're interested in doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the runnable objects in a loop, I guess they are all going to do the same thing? If that's the case, why don't you create one runnable only outside of the loop, and then reuse it in the schedule method?